# No image on Facebook Share after switching to CDN

Tags: wordpress, facebook, share, cdn

We've recently connected KeyCDN on our website and ever since, when we share something on Facebook, the image will not show for most of the times.

What puzzles me the most about this problem is that it won't occur every time. We usually share 10-15 posts on a daily basis on our Facebook page; For half of the shared posts, Facebook will show the picture, but for the other half it will show the Facebook safe picture like below:

[image]

The problem started happening from the day we activated the cdn service (keycdn).

We've used Facebook Share Debugger to see where the problem is, but the pictures display when debugging the problematic shared posts. The only missing property is the fb:app_id, but i don't think that that's the problem?

Here is a [link](https://famagusta.news/local/paralimni/166563/) to one of our posts and a link to the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Ffamagusta.news%2Flocal%2Fparalimni%2F166563%2F)

Comment: Are these articles "new" when you share them, have not been shared before? Then try to pre-scrape them after you published them. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

Comment: Yes, the articles are new and never shared before

Comment: Have you found the cause and solution for this?